# Returning default value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query:

```
SELECT ISNULL(VALUE, '-99') 
FROM PM_VALUE 
WHERE ELEMENT_NAME = 'LL'
```

The problem is that the above query obviously doesn't return anything if it cannot find any record for the `ELEMENT_NAME = 'LL'` condition.

Is there any way I could update it to return a default value `(EX. -99)` in case there is no record as well? I have a requirement where we need some value by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting at most one match for the `WHERE` clause, then the simplest method is aggregation:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(VALUE), '-99')
FROM PM_VALUE
WHERE ELEMENT_NAME = 'LL';
```

An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` returns exactly one row.  If nothing matches the `WHERE`, then the aggregation columns will be `NULL`.  The `COALESCE()` turns the `NULL` into your default value.

Comment: I think DB2 will give a warning in this case.

Comment: @Hogan . . . Really?  What is the warning?  The behavior is well-defined based on the SQL language (although DB2 does harken back to the dark days of SQL before there were standards).

Comment: Something like NULL value skipped in Aggregation -- Don't remember exactly but that is the gist of it.  Totally ignorable warning but if you are like me and want no warning messages at all....

Comment: why dont have a try with adding just a case statement ? -as internally these built in coalesce,nvl etc uses the same logic